# How to implement member functions used in C++ to convert the same program in C?

Tags: c++, c

I need to convert a program from C++ to C, i.e. I need the same program but in C.
I used member functions for a class in C++ but I just know basic level C.
I know this can be done using structures, but how do I implement the class functions for Structure in C?
Here is the code. This is a simple program to make bank accounts and deposit, withdraw or display account status:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

int count = 0;

using namespace std;

class bank
{
public:
    long bal, dep, wdamt; 
    int acno; 
    char name[20], type;
public:
    void set(int x, char n[20], char t)
    {
        acno = x;
        strcpy(name, n);
        type = t;
        bal = 0;
    }
    void deposit(long z)
    {
        bal += z;
        cout << "success!";
    }
    void withdraw(long k)
    {
        bal -= k;
        cout << "success!";
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << "\n Name : " << name << "\n AC BALANCE : " << bal;
    }
};

int main()
{
    bank cust[10];
    int c1, c2, cacno, i = 0, j = 0; 
    long cbal, cdep, cwdamt; 
    char cname[20], ctype;

    while (j < 10)
    {

        cout << "\n \n **** welcome to golu bank ****";
        cout << "\n choose one of the following \n1. New customer \n2. Existing Customer \n 3. Exit";
        cin >> c1;

        switch (c1)
        {
        case 1: cout << "\nnew customer. please enter name. ";
            cin >> cname;
            cout << "\nEnter account type. ";
            cin >> ctype;
            cust[count].set(count, cname, ctype);
            cout << "Hello! Your a/c number is " << cust[count].acno << endl << "PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE:";
            cin.get();
            count++;
            break;
        case 2: cout << "Existing Customer. Enter account number";
            cin >> cacno;
            while (i < 10)
            {
                if (cacno == cust[i].acno)
                {
                    cout << "\n Enter choice! \n 1.Deposit \n 2. Withdraw \n 3. Display\n 4.Exit";
                    cin >> c2;
                    switch (c2)
                    {
                    case 1: cout << "Enter amount to deposit";
                        cin >> cdep;
                        cust[i].deposit(cdep); break;
                    case 2: cout << "Enter amount to withdraw";
                        cin >> cwdamt;
                        if (cwdamt > cust[i].bal)
                            cout << "Insufficent funds!!!";
                        else
                            cust[i].withdraw(cwdamt);
                        break;
                    case 3:  cust[i].display();
                        break;
                    case 4:  i = 11;
                    default: "Invalid choice";
                    }
                }
                else
                    i++;
            }
        case 3: j = 11;
        default: "Invalid choice";
        }
    }
    return 0;
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Hope you haven't used any C++ added since the mid 1990s, and use a CFront compiler. Job done!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Mind expanding a bit?

Comment: Please edit your post and fix the code formatting: this style is completely unreadable. For example, you must include blank lines between functions, as a bare minimum.

Comment: @Lundin I fixed that.

Comment: @GtlsGamr Bathsheba means that if any modern c++ is used, then there is no such thing as conversion. You need to write it in c from scratch, which is easier and faster than attemting to make it "*work*" which is impossible. Also, since you are writing it from scratch, use some concepts of structured programming and use functions to do a single thing that otherwise insert a lot of code into the `main()` and make it impossible to read and understand.

Comment: Oh, and it doesn't even needs to be *that modern*.

Comment: @machine_1 Not really, it is still a complete mess and we aren't doing the OP a favour by fixing it. They need to learn how to write proper source code.

Comment: Put member fields (bal, dep, etc...) into struct instead of class. Extract methods from a class and make them function with this struct passed as an argument. Use stdio.h instead of iostream. Fix minor syntax differences.

Comment: The issue is that do you really want to make the program look like `C`, or be `C` but look like C++?  If it's the latter, note that other `C`-only programmers will wonder why you wrote the code in the way you did, and not use basic `C` idioms.

Answer (score 8):

Following example works as long as you use the C like part of C++. No std or C++ features, that do not have a simple equivalent in C (e.g. templates).

1. Use a struct instead of a class

   ```
   struct prev_class {
       long bal,dep,wdamt; int acno; char name[20], type;
   };
   ```
2. Convert your member functions to free functions using as a first parameter a pointer to that struct:

   ```
   void prev_class_set(struct prev_class* obj, int x, char n[20], char t) {
       obj->acno = x;
       strcpy(obj->name, n);
       obj->type = t;
       obj->bal = 0;
   }
   ```
3. Substitute your C++ specific calls like `cout` or `cin` with C conform functions.

Comment: Also, functions sould be called something like `prev_class_set` ... and so on.

Comment: using typedef struct allows to be able to omit `struct` keyword in function prototypes

Comment: Also virtual functions need to be handled through a function vector or function pointers.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya _function vector_ is not a C term, as far as I know.

Comment: @machine_1 I don't think it's a term at all.

Comment: Errr.. `obj->strcpy` ??

Comment: @machine_1 I meant an array of function pointers.  (I used the term function vector because of similarity to interrupt vectors, pardon me for that)

Answer (score 5):

Roughly like this:

- convert all class methods such as `set` to normal functions (more details below)
- convert all input/output from `cin/cout` to `scanf`/`printf`
- convert `class bank` to `struct bank`, removing all `private:/public:`
- add another `this` parameter to all converted class methods so you can emulate more ore less the C++ `this`, see below

Converted `set` function (the name `set` has been replaced `bank_set`, that is not necessary, but it might prevent name collisions if there was already a free `set` function beforehand):

```
void bank_set(struct bank *this, int x, char n[20], char t)
{
    this->acno = x;
    strcpy(this->name, n);
    this->type = t;
    this->bal = 0;
}
```

Convert calls to class methods e.g like this:

```
cust[count].set(count, cname, ctype);
```

becomes:

```
bank_set(&cust[count], count, cname, ctype);
```

Do the same for all other class methods.

This only works because your C++ program is old fashioned "C-like" C++ and you're not using inheritance.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: "convert class bank to struct bank, removing all private:/public" That's just sloppy. The proper way is to replace the class with an opaque type. There's no reason to toss OO out the door just because you move to C.

Comment: @Lundin that's true, but  the OP wrote _"I just know basic level C"_ so I didn't want to make it any more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Opaque types also require using pointers, so OP can't straightforwardly translate `/*struct*/ bank cust[10];` from the original code

Comment: Well, any would-be programmer has to study OO, no matter which language they settle for. It is a language-agnostic way to design computer programs. Some languages have more built-in support than others.

Comment: Hey man I tried what you told me and it compiles without any errors or warnings, but when i run it, it will force stop when I enter "1" for new customer. It says "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Comment: @GtlsGamr you need to debug this or post another question. You probably misuse `scanf`, but without seeing your actual code it's hard to tell

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yeah, i debugged it. I was using scanf the wrong way. Thanks again!